# Auto date update with datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a datepicker-based calendar which i use not to pick dates, just for displaying current date.

How can i make this calendar automatically update selected date, when date has been changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came out only with this:

```
function updateDate() {
var now = new Date();
    if (now.getDate() != selected_date.getDate()) {
        selected_date = now;
        $( "#calendar" ).datepicker( "setDate", now);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){updateDate()},3000);
}
```